# Formatting currency in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a form with several input fields for entering amounts of money and shows the total at the bottom of the screen. I would like for the user to only be able to type in numeric digits `[0-9]`, then a decimal `.`, and then a maximum of two more digits.

At first, I used the Ember addon [ember-inputmask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-inputmask) which correctly formats the currency as I needed, but if I clicked on an input and clicked out without entering a number or if I only entered part of a number and clicked else where the `total` would equal `NaN`.

I have also attempted to import the jQuery plugin `autonumeric.js` through `npm` and use that but with no success.

What is the best approach to only allow currency to be typed in an input field in Ember?

Is there a better addon or resources on how to accomplish this?

Comment: i dont know exactly how it looks like but i would suggest validation and dont caculate the total if you recognize the input is bad. Or set a default value for the input and always change back to that value unless the input was correct. Either way, you need to check the value manually if you expect a custom format with exactly 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're seeing isn't from `ember-inputmask`. It's an issue with the `total` not being formatted correctly.

You could use a helper to format the total regardless of whether not it's a valid number:

**helpers/fmt-currency.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function fmtCurrency(num) {
  num = +num;

  if (isNaN(num)) { return ''; } // You could set this to 0 if you wanted

  num = num.toFixed(2);

  return num.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)(?=\.))/g, ',');
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(fmtCurrency);
```

**some-template.hbs**

```
${{fmt-currency total}}
```